# Integração sistema desktop e cloud

Tags: json, delphi, rest, firebase, mariadb

Possuo um sistema desktop onde preciso enviar alguns dados para o serviço *Firebase* da *Google*. Gostaria de uma ideia de qual seria a melhor forma para enviar esses dados para o *Firebase*, sendo que pode acontecer ás vezes de não existir conexão com a internet.

Uma breve explicação do que será integrado é o seguinte:
 
Um cadastro de cliente onde se acontecer de um cliente ser cadastrado ou alterado o mesmo deve ser enviado ao *Firebase*.

Até agora o que consegui imaginar foi o seguinte:

1. Criar uma tabela no BD local de "fila" onde a mesma irá armazenar os
   dados a serem enviados;
2. Se possuir conexão com a internet envia os dados da fila para o
   Firebase;
3. Obtendo resposta positiva do Firebase a tabela de fila é esvaziada,
   caso contrário mantém os dados na fila até que haja conexão
   disponível;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite, também penso que seja uma boa saída essa sua, até por que, se não tem conexão à internet no momento não vejo outra forma de fazer o envio dos dados de forma instantânea. Eu tenho alguns sistemas e APPs parecidos, embora, não use o Firebase do Google e sim MySql remoto em um Cloud Amazon. No meu caso, um exemplo de um APP Android, existe uma sincronização ao banco de dados através de um WebService que desenvolvi e que faz os envios e carrega as informações no celular em caso de conexão ativa mantendo-o sempre atualizado, porém, em locais onde não tem conexão com a internet ele armazena em uma "tabela" local e faz o envio posterior, através de um serviço Android que fica executando em segundo plano, tudo de forma transparente ao utilizador. Para mim funciona bem, inclusive, já desenvolvi PDVs com integração fiscal com um principio parecido para transmissão dos dados fiscais.

Para criação de registros no banco de dados funciona perfeitamente para mim assim.

Um cuidado que deve ter é relativo à alteração do registro por dois ou mais usuários ao mesmo tempo sem que este esteja atualizado em um ou ambos os PCs, **caso o seu sistema seja multi-usuário**. Eu contornei isso, de uma certa forma, colocando um campo com a ultima versão da edição do registro no banco e se na hora de fazer o envio para o servidor, o APP verifica se ela é igual à carregada no celular antes da alteração e se não for manda uma mensagem ao usuário perguntando se ele deseja subscrever ou não. Mas isso resolvia pra mim, pode ser que não resolva pra você, tudo depende da necessidade e funcionalidade do sistema que esta criando.

Comment: Bom dia, no caso este serviço em android que executa em segundo plano fica o tempo todo fazendo verificação de conexão para enviar os dados?

Comment: Bom dia. No meu caso, como é um celular faço verificação persistente através da JNI.Network do próprio Android que pode ser implementada pelo Delphi. Fiz um método simples que primeiro verifica se tem dados a serem atualizados e depois dispara a verificação, se não tiver dados, não faz nada. No seu caso, acredito que terá que verificar se tem dados a serem atualizados e se tiver, aí verifica a internet, talvez usando um timer com intervalo de alguns minutos. Eu usaria uma thread para sincronizar em outro processo e não travar a aplicação no momento da verificação.